# Forcing apt update to re-download information

Tags: debian, apt

Is it possible to make `apt update` flush information/re-download information?

`apt update` does not suggest any additional arguments when tab-tabbing in the CLI and returns with `E: The update command takes no arguments` when adding garbage to see what happens.

Also, Debian's apt man-page did not provide any helpful clues: https://manpages.debian.org/buster/apt/apt.8.en.html

I made it work with the following steps, which seems like a bit of a workaround:

1: move away `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list` files

2: run `apt update`; this appears to flush the cache of repositories that is no longer found in a `.list` file

3: move back `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list` files

4: run `apt update` again; with this, information is downloaded from the repositories

Is there any way to do this without juggling `.list` files?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, you can clear `apt`’s index by deleting all the files in `/var/lib/apt/lists`:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/*_*
```

(all index files have underscores in their names, none of the directories in `/var/lib/apt/lists` do).

Comment: I will try this out as soon as I get a chance. Can you say anything additional as to whether this approach is recommended by the creators of apt - with a link to further information if possible? Or is it more of a homegrown solution?

Comment: Can confirm that this works as expected for my case. I did a bit more digging in the apt documentation and the closest I found to a mention of something similar to what is need was in the feature wishlist, and was apparently not very well received: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=873689

Comment: Yes, I dug through the docs and couldn’t find anything...

Comment: If you are running apt upgrade and get 404 errors, this fix also works to solve that problem.